# Angularjs nginx headers are not being set for HTTP POST

Tags: angularjs, ajax, nginx

In development this works, but in production headers are not being set.

Not sure if this is a angular user error or nginx.conf issue.

```
var authentication = ('Basic ' + window.btoa('USERNAME:MYAPIKEY'));
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = authentication;
$http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

var payload = {some: 'data'};
$http({
        url: 'https://some-end-point',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        method: 'POST'
    })
```

When I submit the form, in development content-type and authorization headers are set.  In production, neither are with the request.

-- EDIT

I am logging error, and error object has these headers but request made from browser does not.  What am I missing?

Stringify-ed response with request headers
`"{\"data\":null,\"status\":-1,\"config\":{\"method\":\"POST\",\"transformRequest\":[null],\"transformResponse\":[null],\"url\":\"https://MYENDPOINT\",\"data\":{\"some\":\"data\"},\"withCredentials\":true,\"headers\":{\"Accept\":\"application/json, text/plain, */*\",\"Authorization\":\"Basic VVNFUk5BTUU6TVlBUElLRVk=\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/json;charset=utf-8\"}},\"statusText\":\"\"}"`

Comment: have you checked if this line is fulfilled on production?
var authentication = ('Basic ' + window.btoa('USERNAME:MYAPIKEY'));

Comment: are they not being set or just don't get to the server? e.g. in chrome dev tools in the network tab do you see the data in the request?

Comment: Testing with safari and firefox.  Auth looks like it is being set because angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http').defaults.headers shows Authentication in console.